# Android Studio - Cannot resolve symbol 'com' in build.gradle file

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle

I got this error trying to run my app

[cannot resolve symbol 'com'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkhtL.png)

I am very new developing apps and I have no idea how to fix this issue.

Comment: Probably the package name is changed and it was not refactored properly . Always use refactor to change package name .

Comment: yes! that was the error, the package had another name, so with the refactor option I could find that error and fix it.

Comment: I have posted the comment as answer , select that if that helped your scenario .

Answer (score 0):

Probably the package name is changed and it was not refactored properly . Always use refactor to change package name .